# Jsoup text node split in two by other tag

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have something that look like this

```
<div>
   textA
      <table>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>textB</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   textC
</div>
```

I would like to split it so that it looks like this:

```
textA textB // this is my first string
textC // this is my second string
```

Is there any way to split textA and textC even if they are part of the same node?

Comment: Your HTML snippet is invalid. `tbody` may only be used inside a table tag. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody

Comment: Yeah i know its invalid i just wrote it that way to simplify the question

Comment: so your actual HTML looks different? Why not create something that Jsoup at least parses correctly?

Comment: I changed it so that you could get a better view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to split textA and textC even if they are part of the same node?

What you can do is load the HTML code with Jsoup then ask it to give the whole text. After, you can split this text with `String#split`.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String html = "<div>\n textA\n <table>\n <tbody>\n <tr>\n <td>textB</td>\n </tr>\n </tbody>\n </table>\n textC\n</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element div =doc.select("div").first();
if (div!=null) {
    String[] splittedParts = div.text().split("(?=textC)");

    for(String s:splittedParts) {
        System.out.println(s);                
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
textA textB 
textC
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your answer i actually did exactly that before you answered :). I was wondering if there was anyway around it since im parsing an entire html file and i dont know the content in textC i know some of the content in textA is constant so that is what i have used but its buggy as i am splitting on a string that might also be elsewhere in textA.